# Spring OAuth2 Access Token in HTTP Header

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am attempting to implement a Spring Oauth2 setup with the Authorization Server in an application on its own and Resource Servers in separate applications.

I will say from the outset, that due to current system restrictions, I am forced to use older versions of Spring / Spring Security until such a time that we can plan in a system upgrade:

- Spring: 3.1.1 Spring
- Security: 3.2.7
- Spring OAuth: 1.0.5

I have everything working, however, when I request a restricted resource from the resouce server, I have to provide the access_token as a query paramater.

I would prefer to provide this as an HTTP header. Is there built in functionality to do this within Spring Security Oauth?

Resource Server Config

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Resource Server Filter -->
    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" resource-id="someResourceId" token-services-ref="tokenServices"/>
    <!-- END Resource Server Filter -->

    <!-- Protected resources -->
    <http pattern="/rest/BasicService/**" create-session="stateless" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint">  
        <anonymous enabled="false"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/BasicService/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/> 
    </http>   
    <!-- END Protected resources -->

    <!-- Authentication -->
    <sec:authentication-manager xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" /> 
    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"/>
    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler"/>
    <!-- END Authentication -->         

    <!-- Token Store -->    
    <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.JdbcTokenStore">
        <constructor-arg ref="myJdbcTokenStore" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myJdbcTokenStore" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/someJNDIDatabaseName"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
    </bean>
    <!-- END Token Store -->

</beans>
```

Comment: Add Authorization header like this :::: Authorization : Bearer <your access token here>

Comment: Ah, I tried an authorization header. However I forgot to at the token type.

Comment: My understanding is that the GET request to the secured API location should not require an authentication again... but just to provide the access_token.
Is it correct? I mean... the request to the secured resource should include just the access_token..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by prtk_shah, the token type needs to be added to the Authorization header.

Authorization : Bearer

Answer (score 2):

If you are using spring boot magic maybe by following [their example](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/), you only want to set `authenticationScheme` to `header`. Mission complete.

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      ...
      authenticationScheme: header
```